# How to use DOM features and jQuery in main.js?

Tags: javascript, jquery, firefox-addon, firefox-addon-sdk

I'm working on an add-on using Mozilla's Add-on SDK, and I've come across the need to HTML encode some text (swap out ampersands and special characters for their `&amp;` equivalents). You can do this in JavaScript using the DOM by calling `document.createElement()` and adding text to it (provoking the browser to encode the text). Trouble is, in the privileged code (`main.js`) there is no DOM, so no way to access these features, or even use a library like jQuery.  Is there a best practice here? How can I get access to features that would typically require a global `document` object from `main.js`?

Comment: You have the global 'escape' function? This turns '&' into '%26'

Comment: @canuckistani: I think the question is about parsing HTML entities - and the solution the OP means is `innerHTML` (meaning a huge security hole).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understood correctly, you want to replace HTML entities (`&amp;` and similar) by the actual characters. And your solution so far was:

```js
var text = "foo&amp;bar";
var element = document.createElement('foo');
element.innerHTML = text;
text = element.textContent;
```

Instead of using the DOM of your document (and risking running some script unintentionally) you can use [DOMParser](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/DOMParser) - it will parse text without any side-effects. Unfortunately, accessing `DOMParser` from `main.js` requires [chrome authority](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/developers/docs/sdk/1.10/dev-guide/tutorials/chrome.html) but other than that the code is straightforward:

```js
var text = "foo&amp;bar";
var {Cc, Ci} = require("chrome");
var parser = Cc["@mozilla.org/xmlextras/domparser;1"]
               .createInstance(Ci.nsIDOMParser);
text = parser.parseFromString(text, "text/html").documentElement.textContent;
```

Comment: I actually want to go the other way, from a string that contains special characters and replaces them with HTML entities.  My problem turned out to be a unicode issue unrelated to this, but this is still a good solution to the question I posed :)